# In design mode can I update the content pages after modifying the master page?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I made a master page -> made a content page from that master page -> modified the master page (added content place holder and stuff) -> can I update the content page and reflect those changes made in the master page?
BTY: I'm using VS 2010

Comment: well, have you tried it?

Comment: It won't update on it's own that's for sure. I do them manually now, but is there a VS feature or a plug in that does that?

Comment: Could you write down the steps to reproduce? It seems to work for me. I created a master page with a content placeholder and a calender control. From that master i created a content page. Then I updated the master with a new control and a content placeholder and that change was immediately reflected in the content page designer after saving the master page.

Comment: @PHeiberg is right, all I needed was to go to design view and click **Create Custom Content**. 
:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I needed was to go to design view and click Create Custom Content.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

assuming that the page class is called `MyPage`, in master.cs write this:

```
var page = this.Page as MyPage;
if (page != null)
{
    page.GoCrazy(); // assuming GoCrazy is a public method over there
}
```

Comment: I'm talking about the design ... the aspx page to be updated with the design of the master page.

Comment: Aah - sorry. Design? Who's using design view in VS of anything? JK, no offense - if it works for you, keep doing it. Sorry for misunderstanding the question, though.